# USB power noise insulation (SDR-related)

Tags: usb, insulation, sdr

I am working on a small board which would allow to connect RTL2832 SDR dongle & HF converter to a PC while using power from battery & separate linear regulators.

The idea is to eliminate noise from USB power supply. I wanted to connect data pins of USB connections for PC & RTL2832, and have 1 Megaohm resistor between ground pins, so that ground of the HF part is floating, but somewhere close to PC's ground.

The problem is that inside RTL2832 dongle there in an 1.5KOhm pull-up resistor from it's local 3.3V source to D+ pin (to indicate device speed), and this ruins the whole idea of detaching grounds. This also seems to kill the idea of having an inductor between grounds of PC & HF parts, so that they are insulated for high frequencies (as current through pull-up resistor is different depending on bit being transmitted).

What are the common solutions for this problem, and how can I insulate as much as possible PC & RTL2832+HF converter parts to minimize power & ground noise?

Comment: Have you considered just sticking the thing on a self-powered USB hub? That will likely break a lot of the current paths.

Comment: It might also be worth winding a couple turns of the USB cable connecting the SDR dongle on a ferrite. That might help with some of the HF common-mode noise.

Comment: @ConnorWolf As far as I've seen, self-powered USB hubs all have shared ground for both PC side & ports side. Even with common ground - I am going to go with my solution, as separate linear regulator per port will give lower noise anyway.

Comment: @ConnorWolf Ferrite seems to be a legit idea, although I already tried this with my current (non-battery) setup - and it didn't made much improvement.

Comment: You might look over the [ODAC project](http://nwavguy.blogspot.com/) for ideas, although the designer never really explains in detail his techniques to lower noise from the USB supply.

Comment: @mng - I looked over the schematics for that ODAC project, and it doesn't look like he actually does that much aside from PCB layout and having separate VRegs for the DAC and USB PHY. There is also some interesting ground plane splits, but I'm not sure the exact motivation behind it (the analog and digital sections are joined in an unusual position).

Comment: Some of the parts placement is rather odd, but I don't have the design files to properly ascertain why things are where they are. There is also the standard pi-filter on the USB-rail before it goes into the analog section's vreg, but that's just good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analog Devices offers this part, the ADUM4160, which offers complete isolation between USB input and output, while providing a data path. However, it only supports slow speed 12 Mbps speeds, which won't be enough for wide bandwidth operation.

There are several pre-built isolation boards based on this part, which might be worth looking at.

Comment: Nice part, unfortunately RTL2832 requires 480 Mbps USB (it streams data at ~6Mb/sec)

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure if the RTL2832 did decimation before or after USB. I haven't seen a full speed isolation device yet.

Answer (score 1):

On the subject of reducing RFI when using USB SDRs..

I have currently have four systems using USB SDRs and a pair of them in my radio shed/workshop. The SDRs in the workshop were suffering with RFI that appeared to be from noise getting into the SDRs from the USB cables. All the antennas, coaxial feeders and RF devices are bonded to the "Radio Earth" system which is earthed to a copper ground spike. 
 After some checking and measuring with various meters, spectum analyser and an oscilloscope I have found that the noise was reduced by using good quality, well shielded USB cables from PC to Powered USB Hub and from the hub to the SDRs with ferrite chokes fitted on them at the PC end AND at the SDRs.

There was still extraneous noise getting into my RF gear, including my SDRs, ICOM VHF, AOR wideband scanners, hacker VHF/LW/MW and Westminster LM/MW radios.
I found that a significant amount of the RFI/noise was originating from the domestic AC mains supply with varying amounts of ripple, spikes and RFI present on ALL conductors.

Curing the noise.
This was initially reduced with mains conditioning filters. but there was still some extraneous noise that was getting into the SDRs and other radios raising the noise floor more than calculated when running pre-amps. The amps are good quality inline 14dB and 18dB wideband amps fed by Bias-Tee power injectors with smoothed,regulated DC power supplies. DC power to both the amps and the USB HUB are now fitted with RF Chokes.

The radio shed/workshop is fed 240VAC mains power via a dedicated spur from the domestic split-CU (protected by 30ms MCB/RCBO) in the house. The feeder cable to the workshop is earthed at the supply end to the domestic mains earth in the CU. The feeder cable shielding is earthed at the feeder end but NOT at the workshop CU. The workshop mains is a "T-T earth system" where the 240VAC mains earth for the workshop is ISOLATED from the TNC Domestic supply earth and bonded to its own dedicated copper ground spike(s). (This is NOT connected to the Radio Earth) If you don`t understand exactly how TNC/TNC-S and T-T protective earthing works DO NOT just have a go. Earthing power systems requires much measurement and calculation to ensure electrical safety. If in doubt, call a sparky out!

The Laptop PC that runs the SDR software is itself grounded to the "Radio Earth" and its 19VDC power supply lead is also fitted with ferrite chokes. Note: the laptop power supply unit is earthed normally through its AC power lead to the AC MAINS T-T EARTH of the workshop.

This seems like a lot of work but it has significantly reduced the noise floor level on all my radio equipment not just the SDRs, this has improved signal to noise ratios and made a significant difference in operable range especially when running amps/pre-amps.

The USB HUB and SDRs are also housed in a steel enclosure that is bonded to the workshop Radio Earth to stop RFI produced by other equipment in the workshop getting to the SDRs.

- Have fun, but above all, STAY SAFE...